# Spacetime/spacetime interval in the light of this inquiry

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, causality

As far as we know and the physics we have, Einstein's theory has been proven correct.
So we are left to say.  That time and space as we intuively know them to be absolute and written in stone, they are not.  That rug has been pulled from under us.  No wonder we get stressed about the whole thing. At least  I do.

Then the theory goes on to say that what is actually real and absolute is Spacetime Interval.  Not only that but it is something everyone actually agrees on.
And just what is Spacetime Interval happens to mean, it is the order of events. Specifically causal connection between two events.
And what is an event, it is not to be found in some place in particular or in some moment in time as we know it.

So my question is obvious:
I can't ask where or when to find this?
We only have two system here.  Objective and subjective.

It is clearly not objective, it is clearly not subjective or personal belonging to one person.

I can't ask what is it, because it is not a what.
What combination of words, terms describes it?  Is it right to point to a drawing on piece of paper?
Or in the form of writing words such as: It is a concept that is real, it is not to be found outside or inside or some such thing.

Frankly I don't know how to say it without seeing a puzzle look on onother person's face and then blame them for not getting it.

So how would you describe it without big words because you don't want to blame the other person for not getting it epecially when you realize the other genuinely wants to expand their minds beyond the cages of the old.
You don't want to kill the quest before it had a chance to take roots.

How would you explain to a new mind, a young fella what spacetime interval is, without some manifolds, geometrical stuff, some nebulous asbstractions he can't put his fingers on?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the theory/mathematics an event is a point in a 4D pseudo-Riemannian (Lorentzian) manifold.

I terms of experiment/observation it is any identifiable place and time. The event can be identified by some physically realized coordinate system or by some brief localized physical occurrence, like a collision.

Although people may use different coordinates to refer to a given event, the event itself is an invariant geometric object.

EDIT: the spacetime interval, also known as the metric, describes the geometry of spacetime. Ordinary spatial geometry has distances, which can be measured with rulers. Spacetime is more complicated since it involves time as well as space. $$ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 +dy^2 + dz^2$$ Note that this looks like the ordinary spatial arc length formula with the extra $c^2 dt^2$ term for time.

So the spacetime interval includes both distances measured with rulers and also durations measured with clocks. It fully describes the geometry of spacetime. But to do so it must have some means to encode when the geometry is to be measured with a ruler and when it is to be measured with a clock.

When $ds^2 > 0$ the interval is measured with a ruler and is called a spacelike interval. When $ds^2 < 0$ the interval is measured with a clock and is called a timelike interval. Often timelike intervals are written in terms of proper time $d\tau^2 = -ds^2/c^2$.